# Vuejs, How can I resolve expressions within a string got as a prop?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm sorry if this is already solved but I'm not able to find it so I gonna try to be quick.

Imagine one of the props received by my component has the following value:

```
myAnnoyingProp: "Position of {{$data.name}} {{maritalStatus?\'married\':\'free\'}}"
```

I tried the following two options but I've got the same result for both:

```
<label v-html="element.label"></label>
<label>
  {{element.label}}
</label>
```

Expected result:
Position of TheNameSetted free

Obtained result:
Position of {{$data.name}} {{maritalStatus?\'married\':\'free\'}}

PD: I'm using Vue 2.4.2

Comment: Provide the code of your component please. Seems you are registering a component prop incorrect

Answer (score 0):

You could move the login inside your component by making use of 2 props, for example `name`, which is a `String`, and `maritalStatus`, which is either a `String` or `Boolean` depending on your needs (the example assumes a Boolean for `maritalStatus`). Then inside your component construct the message you want to display:

```
<label>
  Position of {{element.name}} <span v-if="maritalStatus">Free</span><span v-else>Married</span>
</label>
```

You could also use [string literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```
myAnnoyingProp: `Position of ${name} ${maritalStatus}`
```